# Only one .gitignore for multiple projects

Tags: git

I have these projects in directories:

```
/client
  /node_modules
  ...
/server
  /node_modules
  ...
```

And I want to have one git project with one .gitignore file for both projects.

Can I do something like this:

```
/client
  /node_modules
  ...
/server
  /node_modules
  ...
/.gitignore
```

And if so what should I change in the .gitignore file to ignore node_modules directory in both projects?

Right now I have this for node_modules:

```
# dependencies
/node_modules
/.pnp
.pnp.js
```

Should I rewrite it to something like:

```
# dependencies
/client/node_modules
/server/node_modules
/.pnp
.pnp.js
```

Or not?

Comment: `.gitignore` can be setup globally, just place it in home directory, but this is not good idea. It will impact only your machine. If someone wish to checkout same repo it is preferred he sees same `.gitignore` settings.

Comment: You can also put files to ignore in `~/git/ignore`, which will be used by `git` regardless of which repository you working on. Patterns to be shared by some but not all repositories could also be managed by using `core.excludesFile` to reference a file in addition to `.gitignore`.

Comment: Git itself *can* do this. Whether it's a good idea to store both client and server projects in a single repository is debatable (but not on StackOverflow!). See, e.g., [this CircleCI blog post on the topic](https://circleci.com/blog/monorepo-dev-practices/).

Answer (score 0):

What you said was right but you could also write it like this:

```
/**/node_modules
```

so it ignores any node_modules file inside folders.

Comment: Or simply just unanchored: `node_modules/`

Comment: what about package-lock.json inside each node_modules/ ?

Answer (score 0):

With a single, you can have one Git repository. gitignore file that is applicable to both separate directories of projects. You can use relative paths in your to ignore the node _ modules directory in both projects. gitignore file

Here is how your can be organized. gitignore file:

```
# Ignore node_modules in both client and server directories
/client/node_modules
/server/node_modules

# Ignore other dependencies if needed
/.pnp
.pnp.js

# Add any other patterns or rules as necessary
```

Git will disregard the node _ modules directory in both the client and server directories with this configuration. Ensure that this... The client and server directories of your Git repository are both located in the root directory, where the .gitignore file is placed.